# honeycomb lattice in continuum limit

Tags: condensed-matter

for TB model when we want to go to the continuum limit in real space in magnetic field (on square lattice) we use this relation
[image]

and if we expand the bracket the current operator will appear

now i want to use this application for honeycomb lattice but we have two basis and hopping term is between A,B sub-lattice

[image]

and near Dirac point and in magnetic field, Hamiltonian is linear and proportional

H=hv(P-A)

but with this Hamiltonian i did not find current operator. is it true that we consider hopping term in external magnetic field in this way?
[image]

and say honeycomb Hamiltonian is achieved by expansion exponential up to second order of A ?

thanks